# Why are .NET dictionaries whiny?

Tags: .net, vb.net, dictionary

In .NET if you ask a dictionary for the value associated with a key that it doesn't have, an exception is thrown.  You can get around this by calling `TryGetValue` but I find it use of a Ref var abominable.

What this means is that you generally have to guard against missing keys by first checking if the key exists (`ContainsKey`) and this just seems cumbersome.

In Ruby if you asked a hash for the value associated with a key you wouldn't get an exception.  It would just give back some default value which you can change if you want.  This makes working with a hash more pleasant.

Is there some reason why .NET dictionaries fuss over missing keys that makes them more useful?

Comment: Answer: Because the VB developers wanted it that way :P. Python's dict throw exceptions as well, C#. When you're developing a library you get to decide how to do things. They wanted to do it that way :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that a default value simply isn't a definitive answer that the key was not in the dictionary.  For example in .Net the default value for a class is `null`.  This is a completely acceptable value for any ref type and hence can be used as a key.

```
Dictionary<int, string> map = ...;
map.Add(42, null);  // OK
```

Let's assume for a second that `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` did return the default value when a key was missing.  In that world the following code would fail

```
void FillValue(Dictionary<int, string> map, int value) { 
  if (map[value] == null) {  
    map.Add(value, "");
  }
}
```

This code will fail in the cases where `value` was already present in the dictionary with the value `null`.  It would throw because `Add` requires the value to not be present in order to execute correctly.

The bottom line is that having the default value represent the missing case creates unavoidable ambiguities in the code.  The current design of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` avoids ambiguity whenever possible

Also do note that the design of `Hashtable` is as you suggested (missing value returns `null`).  .Net went away from this design in part because of the ambiguity problem it creates.

Comment: You can always ask `ContainsKey` if that is relevant.  But for all intents and purposes why is null being returned from 42 matter enough to make that distinction?  In most cases, the way I write code, the consequence of that has no bearing.

Comment: @Mario: The BCL collections are designed to be general collections. Not only for "the way you write code".

Comment: @Mario Sure you could always use `ContainsKey` in that scenario but then you're paying the lookup cost twice (once for `ContainsKey` and the other for `[]`).  `TryGetValue` does both operations and only pays the lookup cost once.  Lookup in a dictionary strives to be O(1) but even O(1) does not mean "instant".  It's often a very involved operation

Comment: +1. Regarding your last comment, I never had a performance bottleneck tied to doing two lookups on a dictionary instead of one. It's usually something else. :)

Comment: @JaredPar: the default value for a <strike>class</strike> reference object is null.

Comment: @JaredPar: You might mention in your answer that for highly specific use cases that disallow null values in the dictionary one could write a class that inherited from dictionary<TKey, TValue> and provided the behavior that the op is looking for.  Or he could use extension methods to provide that to existing dictionary instances.

Comment: @Neolisk I've actually found far too many perf issues related to double lookups. They usually weren't bottlenecks but several times I've reduced scenarios by 5-15% simply by removing a double lookup.

Comment: @Dan-o actually he really can't fix this with inheritance.  All of the members on `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` are non-virtual hence nothing to override. Extension method would be the better choice

Comment: @JaredPar: ah. Thank you.  I suppose encapsulation would work ok.. but that's more work than the extension method.

Comment: @JaredPar: Which makes sense. It's just that in my projects 10% rarely made a difference. The last major optimization I remember doing improved performance by ~95%. And that was based totally on CPU profiler data, no issues with extra lookups there. :) But, as always, it's good to know where to be looking. With random code assignments, I typically start with refactoring it to start using a dictionary, and that improves performance by like 100 times (compared to not using a dictionary), then just leave it at that. For reference, yes, I use TryGetValue all the time, being more of a habit rly. :)

Comment: @Neolisk 10% makes an enormous difference on projects

Answer (score 2):

Note: For those of you coming from just the Ruby world or just the C# world, Ruby's maps are comparable to C#'s dictionaries.

I would say that this is desired, particularly in idiomatic C#. In Ruby, you can declare variable simply by initializing it, much like you can retrieve a default value from a hash for an uninitialized key (or initialize a value in the same manner, for that matter).

Ruby:

```
some_variable = 40
retrieved_value = some_hash['key'] // returns default string
```

C#:

```
int some_variable = 40;
Dictionary<string,string> someDictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();
string retrievedValue = someDictionary["key"]; // THROWS EXCEPTION
someDictionary.Add("key", "value");
```

It seems in static languages like C#, the idea is to know beforehand that something is going to work as you expect before trying it. Instead of having a fallback (like the Ruby default value), C# instead expects you to know that there is something there before you try to access it.

You might think of the Ruby hash retrieval as having **two behaviors**. If there's a value there, it retrieves it. If not, it is initialized as a default. I think that this is the reason C# does not handle it this way. Most significantly, the purpose of the statement (whether it's acquisition of an existing variable or the intentional creation of one) is usually ambiguous unless the context is observed, and can difficult even with context.

---

An interesting aside, however, is how C# handles *assignment* to a dictionary. Everything shown up until now has a clear distinction between imperative C# and the expressive Ruby. However, in C#, you are allowed to do something like this:

```
Dictionary<int,int> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int,int>;
myDictionary[3] = 4;
```

which is just shorthand for the following **only if key `3` doesn't exist in the dictionary**

```
myDictionary.Add(3,4);
```

And herein we see some of the potential ambiguity that was present in the Ruby hash retrieval; `myDictionary[3] = 4;` will do one thing if the dictionary doesn't have a `3` entry (initialize a new one to `4`) and another thing if it does have a `3` entry (replace its current value with 4).

Alternatively, `myDictionary.Add(3,4);` **will throw an exception if it already has an entry for `3`**. This, to me, feels more like a static imperative language where I'm implying "I know that `myDictionary` doesn't have 3 as a key and now I am adding it" whereas the other syntax along with Ruby's feel less committal.

EDIT: Added distinction between `dictionary.Add()` and `dicitonary[3]=4` thanks to Neolisk

Comment: +1, with a side note. `myDictionary[3] = 4;` also allows reassignment. `myDictionary.Add(3,4);` would throw an exception, if an entry already exists. So these statements are not exactly equivalent.